# matplotlib plotting tuple as line

Tags: matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot((0,1))
plt.show()
```

The above plots a line:

[image]

How is it that one tuple produces a line like this? It seems like it should represent just one point.

Comment: Tuples seem to work like lists and arrays as explained here: ["If you provide a single list or array to plot, matplotlib assumes it is a sequence of y values, and automatically generates the x values for you."](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#intro-to-pyplot)

Comment: Ah. Simple. Thank you.